# Animation on RecyclerView when performing multiple insert/removal (not in single range)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

For `RecyclerView`, when we insert one or remove an item, we could have it animate in using the below API:

```
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(...)
// within the adapter
notifyItemInserted(position);
// or 
notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

Even for a range that change, we could use

```
notifyItemRangeInserted(...)
// or
notifyItemRangeRemoved(...)
```

However, if I have multiple items inserted/removed, but they are not in a range, is it possible to still have the needed animation?

e.g. I'm inserting A, B, D, G ... into a list of C, E, F, H... hence I get A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H.... where the appropriate animation should show A, B and D and G inserted, while C, E, F and H animate down/up to allow the feel of insertion. Just like the single insertion/removal, but done with multiple item in parallel.

I'm okay, if a Library could help perform that as well.

I don't think https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators and https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/RecyclerViewItemAnimators could achieve that. I hope I am wrong though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dispatch as many of them as you want. RecyclerView batches all adapter changes until the next layout pass and executes them together.

so in your case of inserting `A, B, D, G` into `C, E, F, H` to get `A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H`, you can dispatch:

`notifyItemRangeInserted(0, 2);` //insert A,B, list becomes: ABCEFH

`notifyItemInserted(3);` //insert D, list becomes: ABCDEFH

`notifyItemInserted(6);` // insert G, list becomes: ABCDEFGH

And RecyclerView will animate all of them together.

Comment: seems like batching didn't work for me... I tried removing a column from grid, so I have non-continuous indexes to be removed, but animation was not as I expected. Here is my original question, would be great if you could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40455926/android-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-column-removal-animation

Answer (score 1):

I manage to achieve what I want using DiffUtil. It could insert and remove list simultenousely or even swap order. A demo app of what I have done as shown in GIF below. You'll find more information in More elaboration in https://medium.com/@elye.project/simultaneous-insertion-and-removal-of-recyclerview-with-animation-f9e1800a3dd0#.3evndq4is

[image]